# Pytube Path not found

Tags: python, youtube, pytube

I am not sure why this code works for some videos but sometimes I get this error.
the error is:

```
MoviePy error: the file /Users/xxx/xxxxx/xxxxxx).mp4 could not be found!
```

My code:

```py
def convertSong(self):

    try:
        MP4 = "{}{}.mp4".format(self.MP4_path,self.title)
        MP3 = MP4.replace("mp4","mp3")
        videoclip = VideoFileClip(MP4)
        audioclip = videoclip.audio
        audioclip.write_audiofile(MP3)
        audioclip.close()
        videoclip.close()

    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception!!")
        print(e)
```

Comment: Are you sure `/Users/xxx/xxxxx/xxxxxx).mp4` is a valid path? Because it seems like it contains a probably unecessary `)` character just before `.mp4`.

Comment: yeah i just add this by mistake in the question, Thanks!. any way i found the solution few hours after posting the question